# Changing hard drive name in single user mode - Mac OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos

I stupidly changed my hard drives names through the info pane and then shut down my computer and now it won't let me log in. I was trying to remove the spaces in the names so I can run a certain program for school.

How do I change my hard drives names through the single user mode? I've never used single user mode before so I'm completely lost when it comes to this.

UPDATE: I'm running a hackintosh so using cmd/R won't work. I can really only get into single user mode. It's not that OSX won't load it just wont let me log in. Also super user won't let me comment so I hope you see this update.

Comment: Changing the boot drive name shouldn't prevent the machine from booting. Did you try a repair from boot up, Cmd/R ?

Answer (score 0):

As Testujin-san suggests, boot or restart your Mac while holding down the Cmd and R keys.

Your Mac will reboot from the recovery partition and open OS X Utilities.

Quite OS X Utilities, you'll get a pop up on the OS X Utilities windows entitled:

`Are You sure you want to quit OS X Utilities?`

There's a `Choose Startup Disk` button which will lead to a window showing bootable disks on your system, presumably with the name(s) you changed yours to.

Select it and then reboot.

You can also hold down the Option key while booting which will lead you to a graphic with representations of bootable disks, one of which you can select to boot from.

Once up in multi-user mode you can use System Preferences -> Startup Disk and set the start up disk. Notice the `Restart...` button.  This is the step  you were missing after changing the disk Name using the finder info popup window.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for completeness sake, not that it’ll help. :D

List disk information:

```
diskutil info
```

Change name:

```
diskutil rename /dev/disk0s2 "New Name"
```

...where `/dev/disk0s2` has to be replaced with the volume to rename, of course.

**Update**

Well, I just tried it out myself (should’ve done that first) and there’s something preventing `diskutil` from running in single-user mode on Mavericks. It just crashes with `Killed: 9`. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to start your Mac on Target Disk Mode?

Once you do it and connect it to another computer, you should be able to change the label from the second computer:

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10725?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US